# Why does my whirlpool ice maker make ice, quit for several weeks, then start again?

Tags: kitchens, refrigerator, ice-maker

I have a Whirpool side-by-side with an in door ice dispensing system.  I have been having an issue with the ice maker for some time now.  I thought the ice maker was defective because it would make ice for a while then just stop, and a few weeks would go by and it would start making ice again.  So, I replaced the ice maker.  The replacement ice maker is doing the same thing.  It fills the tray with water and freezes it, but won't dump it.  Then all of the sudden it will work for a while, then stop again.  Any ideas about what might be going on?

Comment: I think the answer is not the full tray because that's obvious that would be checked first, the answer might not have anything to do with the ice maker since it was changed. There are factory settings that might need adjusting that area must not be campatible with factory settings

Comment: Every ice maker problem I've had has been solved with a hairdryer. But that may say more about my problems than it does about hairdryers.

Answer (score 2):

Refrigerator ice makers are designed to stop when the ice holding receptacle is full. How often do you dispense ice? Are you sure the ice maker has stopped when the receptacle is not full? There is usually some sort of arm that gets raised as the receptacle fills up and when it is high enough, it shuts off the ice maker. Check to see if that arm is working properly.